# Blog with mathjax seen on a cellphone

Tags: html, mobile, blogger, mathjax, blogspot

I'm using mathjax in [my blogspot blog](http://ochopatas.blogspot.mx/) and it works well when seen in a computer, but formulas don't transform when seen on a cellphone. I found this [other blogspot blog](http://imflaud.blogspot.mx/2016/07/invisible-hand-games.html) where its formulas can be seen on a cellphone. Why? How can I make my blog transform formulas when seen on a cellphone too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the Mathjax script (as seen below) is not loading in the mobile template.

```
<script src='//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML,http://flengyel.github.io/mathjaxconfig.js,http://sonoisa.github.io/xyjax_ext/xypic.js' type='text/javascript'>
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [
            ['$', '$'],
            ["\\(", "\\)"]
        ],
        displayMath: [
            ['$$', '$$'],
            ["\\[", "\\]"]
        ],
    },
    "HTML-CSS": {
        availableFonts: ["TeX"]
    }
});
</script>
```

To make it work on Mobile templates, you will have to enable Custom mobile template by going into **Theme** > **Gear Icon** > Selecting **Custom** from the **Choose mobile theme** dropdown, Refer to the image below -

[image: Enable Custom mobile template on Blogger]

Comment: Before I asked the question, I did that, but it's not working.

Comment: Is there any kind of `b:if` condition which is wrapping around the above code in your template? Also, I checked the template source code, it seems that the Custom option is not currently enabled. Just one thing, choosing Awesome from the dropdown list in the mobile template will not make the code work. Explicitly selecting the Custom option is the only way

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, cf. https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/.