# Blogger math not readable from an Android browser

Tags: android, html, blogger, mathjax

I have a small free blog on Google's blogger.

I have installed MathJax in my blog using this code section

```
    <script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {
          inlineMath: [ [&#39;$&#39;,&#39;$&#39;], [&quot;\\(&quot;,&quot;\\)&quot;] ],
          displayMath: [ [&#39;$$&#39;,&#39;$$&#39;], [&quot;\\[&quot;,&quot;\\]&quot;] ],
          processEscapes: true
        },
        &quot;HTML-CSS&quot;: { availableFonts: [&quot;TeX&quot;] }
      });
    </script>
    <script async='async' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML,Safe' type='text/javascript'>
    <!-- <script async='async' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js' type='text/javascript'> -->
    </script>
```

This has been put in the theme's HTML on Blogger.

I have no idea really what it's doing, I simply found some instructions
how to add MathJax to a blogger blog on some site, and these instructions
seemed to work OK (at least for desktop browser).

So the math formulas, equations, etc. show correctly on desktop but not
on mobile (Android). How can I make it show correct math even in Android?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blog with mathjax seen on a cellphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592013/blog-with-mathjax-seen-on-a-cellphone)

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Changing the setting is slightly different now. But this answer did help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Seems it's slightly different to get to that setting today. I posted an answer to describe how it can be done. Once again, thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped and thanks for posting an update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today it's kind of different to get to that setting.

The procedure is not quite as described here

[Blog with mathjax seen on a cellphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592013/blog-with-mathjax-seen-on-a-cellphone)

So here are the instructions.

1. In the Blogger admin panel, click on **Theme**.
2. Click on that **drop down arrow** near the customize button.

[image: pic001]

3. Click on **Mobile settings**
4. Select the **Mobile** radio button and select **custom** from the drop-down.

[image: pic002]

5. Save your changes and you're done.